# C++ DLL crash (reading/writing crash related I think)

Tags: c++

Bit of a weird situation.  I have a C++ dll that was made for me that injects into a 3rd party app and retrieves information.  This dll originally would just output the information but I needed to use it in a VB app I made.

So I made another C++ dll that has 2 call back functions from the original C++ dll .. this is where the information is sent.   And has functions that my VB app can call to retrieve that information.

I am not very good with C++.. I've been messing around with this for awhile and lowered the occurrence of the crashes but it still happens (very rarely though).  I think at some point 2 different parts are reading or writing to the same address that causes the crash.
Here is the code:

This is a global cstring that I use to store the information from the call back function and to send to VB

```cpp
class Global
{
public:

    static CString &  get_allstacks() {
        static CString allstacks; return allstacks; }
};
```

This is the function that I call from VB that sends me the info.

```cpp
BSTR _stdcall vbFunction()
{
    BSTR Message;
    int len = Global::get_allstacks().GetLength();
    Message = SysAllocStringByteLen ((LPCTSTR)Global::get_allstacks(), len+1 );
    return Message;

}
```

This is one of the call back functions.. there is another one that also puts info into the same global cstring.  In this function it also resizes the cstring when it reaches >100k length.  Note the resizing code is only in 1 of the callbacks.

```cpp
HANDLE OnInfo(SendInfo* info)
{
    strcpy_s(tempID,200,info->GameId);
    CString stringTempID="";
    stringTempID=tempID;

    CString tempRound="";
    strcpy_s(round,200,info->round);
    tempRound=round;

    // get a reference to global string
    CString & allstacks= Global::get_allstacks();
    // add new info
    allstacks+=  stringTempID + tempRound + "\n";

    //resize cstring
    int len =allstacks.GetLength();
    if  (len > 100000)
    {
        int nstart = 0;
        int npos  = 0;

        while ((npos = allstacks.Find(_T('\n'), nstart)) < len - 50000) {
            nstart = npos+1;
        }   

        allstacks= allstacks.Right(nstart);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Incase this is needed

```
char* tempID =new char[255];
char* round=new char[255];
```

Anyways the crash is super rare, it has occurred a few times when vbFunction is called but the majority of the times it happens without vbFunction being called, so I assume the problem is also occurring in the callback functions.

Comment: Hi Andre,

As far as I know no, but I am not very good at this stuff :).  It's possible that the callback functions are in a different thread?  If I had to do something specifically to make multi threading, then the answer should be no.

Comment: Can you pinpoint where the crash occurs? Save a crash dump and open it in VS, for example.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you.  I don't know how to save a crash dump.. going to google it now.

Thanks

Comment: @user1088794 You can search on stackoverflow or ask in another question how to save a crash dump. Something else you can do is use `OutputDebugString` at the start and end of each function. Use DebugView or visual studio to watch the output. That way you can not only see in which function it crashes, but also if the callbacks are fired in multiple threads. For example if the output includes `OnInfo start, OnFunc2 start, OnInfo return, OnFunc2 return` you know it must be two different threads. Your code is not thread safe, so that can cause a crash.

Comment: Thanks Wimmel, thats a great idea I am going to output it to a text file, the crash is so rare that itll likely not occur if I try to watch it :).  I am going to do that for now and continue to read about crash dump.

Comment: @Wimmel Thanks again, just did the start/end logging idea and the callbacks are fired in multiple threads.  
"start function1" "start function2" "end function2" "end function1" etc occurs.

So now we know whats causing the crash :)