# Multi thread C++ dll global variable causing crash

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a small C++ dll that has 2 callback functions that retrieve information from another dll.

These 2 callback functions are being called repeatedly in more than 1 thread.

They both add information to the same global Cstring variable.

I have another function that the program that uses this dll will call that reads this variable.

It is rare, but sometimes I get a crash and its definitely due to this global variable being read/written to at the same time by 2 different functions.

I am not very experienced with multithreads, so I don't really know what to do.

Any suggestions?

here is a previous question I posted about the same problem with a bit more info..(and some of the code).
One of the users assisted me in confirming that it was a multithread issue and we didnt get much further than that.

[C++ DLL crash (reading/writing crash related I think)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461206/c-dll-crash-reading-writing-crash-related-i-think)

Comment: 'They both add information to the same global Cstring variable' - why?  Can you not change your design so that this operation goes away?

Comment: crap, I am sorry I'm wrong.  The callback functions both add information to different global cstrings.  

But since those function are running in the multiple threads, sometimes function 1 is being called a bunch at the same time.

Also the other function that is called sometimes reads both those variables.

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of [Thread Synchronization for Beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7953/Thread-Synchronization-for-Beginners).

If you're using MFC then [`CMutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt45160e%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) may be appropriate.

Comment: Agreed, but the questions mention CString

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a critical section on this variable. In Windows, you can do it by using [Mutex Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).